# Cannot access newly created wordpress table

Tags: php, wordpress, insert

I have created a new table in the wordpress database via PhpMyAdmin.
However I have not be able to write into any of the tables that I have created. Writing in the predefined tables such as metapost works just fine with the same code. When I write out the error it seems that wordpress believes that I "forgotten" to enter the table name, like wordpress is not aware that this new table exists. What is going on?
The name of my table is hest

**Here is my code:**

```
    <?php
    $metakey   = 'THAT IS';
    $metavalue = 'DONE.';
     
    $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->hest
    ( meta_key, meta_value )
    VALUES ( %s, %s)
    ",
    $metakey,
    $metavalue
    )
    );
    $wpdb->show_errors();           
    echo $wpdb->last_query;         
    ?>
```

**Here is the show_error message:**
As you can see the table name is suddenly gone in the executed query.

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( meta_key, meta_value ) VALUES ( 'THAT IS', 'DONE.')' at line 2]
INSERT INTO ( meta_key, meta_value ) VALUES ( 'THAT IS', 'DONE.')

Thanks a bunch!!

Cheers Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation it seems that only the default [tables](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#tables) are available as properties on the `wpdb` class. You would need to reference your new table as a string.

```php
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    INSERT INTO hest
    ( meta_key, meta_value )
    VALUES ( %s, %s)
    ",
    $metakey,
    $metavalue
    )
);
```

You could alternatively use the [insert function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#insert-row) to insert a row to your new table.

```php
$wpdb->insert( 
    'hest', 
    array( 
        'meta_key' => $metakey, 
        'meta_value' => $metavalue, 
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Hey SpeedyLom, excellent answer. Thanks for that. I do not fully understand why since it would make sense that plugins would create tables within the Wordpress database?? How would you approach making a table that can be used for your website and where (in what database) would you place it? Thank again!!

Comment: Hi Christian, you are able to create and use custom tables within your WordPress they just aren't available as properties on `wpdb` class.